# Как можно сделать ссылку на структуру?

Tags: c#, структуры

Мучает вопрос, как можно сделать ссылку на структуру?
Например:

```
Point p = new Point(0, 0);
this._point;
void foo(ref Point p)
{
    // p.X = 100; // можно бы так, но мне нужно сохранить ссылку
    this._point = p;
    this._point.X = 100;
}
```

после этого кода поля точки не меняются

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример кода немного странный и я не очень понимаю, что вы в нем хотите сделать и что не получается. Приведу на эту же тему банальный пример на основе вашего кода: метод меняет местами значения именно за счет того, что объекты структур передаются в метод по ссылке, то есть внутри метода мы оперируем ссылками на те же области в памяти, что и в вызывающем коде.

```
   public class Program
    {
        static void foo(ref Point p1, ref Point p2)
        {
            var p3 = p1;
            p1 = p2;
            p2 = p3;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            var point1 = new Point(1, 1);
            var point2 = new Point(2, 2);

            foo(ref point1, ref point2);
        }
    }
```